# ShapeBorder has rectangle jutting out of it

Tags: flutter

Does anyone know why my custom `ShapeBorder` has a small rectangle jutting out of the bottom of it only on iPhone 14 simulator? I'm fairly sure it is the `ShapeBorder` and not the menu items because I made the menu items have empty `SizedBox()` children, and the issue persisted.

[image]

code:

```
class CenteredTooltipShape extends ShapeBorder {
  final BorderSide _side = BorderSide.none;

  final BorderRadiusGeometry _borderRadius = BorderRadius.zero;
  const CenteredTooltipShape();

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.all(_side.width);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(
    Rect rect, {
    TextDirection? textDirection,
  }) {
    final Path path = Path();

    path.addRRect(
      _borderRadius.resolve(textDirection).toRRect(rect).deflate(_side.width),
    );

    return path;
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    final Path path = Path();
    final RRect rrect = _borderRadius.resolve(textDirection).toRRect(rect);

    // starting position
    path.moveTo(0, 10);
    // corner
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 10, 0);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width / 2 - 10, 0);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width / 2, -10);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width / 2 + 10, 0);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width - 10, 0);
    // corner
    path.quadraticBezierTo(rrect.width, 0, rrect.width, 10);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width, rrect.height - 10);
    // corner
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        rrect.width, rrect.height, rrect.width - 10, rrect.height,);
    path.lineTo(10, rrect.height);
    // corner
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, rrect.height, 0, rrect.height - 10);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: _side.scale(t),
        borderRadius: _borderRadius * t,
      );
}
```

Probably just a bug in Flutter. I can't replicate on other devices.

Comment: Have you tried clipping it with `Clip.antiAlias`. Sometimes it causes these types of problem. Also, is your path drawn correctly. Probably that is causing the problem.